# IE8 - Browser Zoom-out script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, zooming

I've been trying to figure out a simple zoom-out script in **IE8** upon page load but am unable to obtain the desired results.

Basically once the page loads, I want it to zoom out to **50%** and be in full screen mode <kbd>F11</kbd>.

I have tried the following:

1. `document.body.style.zoom = "50%"`
2. `<style>
   div

   {

   transform: scale(0.5,0.5);

   zoom: 0.5;

   }

   </style>`
3. `<body style="zoom: 50%">`

But am still unsuccessful as the entire page becomes unviewable and distorted.

My code is as below:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="body">

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=Max();
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML=Zoom();

var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},5000);

function myTimer()
{
var d=new Date();
var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t;
setTimeout("javascript:HereLink('d:dashboard~p:i3pub16he83q7e9c~r:qqq9loggk8hvpl85',
'Refresh');",5000);
}

function max() {
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
}

 function zoom() {
        document.body.style.zoom = "50%" 
}
```

Comment: Proper browsers implement a [full screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

Answer (score 0):

just try

div
  {
  zoom: 0.5;
  }

looks like 'transform ' rotates a div element. that is probably not what you want.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: the page becomes unviewable when I try
    div
    {
    zoom:0.5;
    }